# Gurobi Build Issues with Drake

Tags: drake

I'm trying to build drake with Gurobi and am getting several issues. I should note that I am treating drake as a package in my ROS workspace, and that has been working well so far.

1. After successfully building with `--config=gurobi`, and running a test file, I get the error:

```
/home/user/test_ws/devel/lib/simple_test/simple_test: error while loading shared libraries: libdrake_lcm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This doesn't happen when I omit `--config=gurobi`.

2. After building again, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test_ws/build/drake/_bazel_user/c0701f1e1e0381b11260fb3e4da5ea58/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/install.runfiles/drake/tools/install/installer.py", line 485, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/user/test_ws/build/drake/_bazel_user/c0701f1e1e0381b11260fb3e4da5ea58/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/install.runfiles/drake/tools/install/installer.py", line 478, in main
    exec(f'installer.{action}')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/test_ws/build/drake/_bazel_user/c0701f1e1e0381b11260fb3e4da5ea58/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/install.runfiles/drake/tools/install/installer.py", line 169, in install
    self.copy_or_link(src, dst_full)
  File "/home/user/test_ws/build/drake/_bazel_user/c0701f1e1e0381b11260fb3e4da5ea58/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/install.runfiles/drake/tools/install/installer.py", line 145, in copy_or_link
    os.symlink(relative_link, dst)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: './libgurobi.so.9.5.2' -> '/home/user/test_ws/install/lib/libgurobi95.so'
```

Manually deleting that existing file solved the issue, but having to constantly remove this file is problematic.

[UPDATE]

I'm now explaining my current build setup. I have a ros workspace organized as

```
test_ws/
    build/
    devel/
    ...
    src/
        drake/
        simple_test/
            CMakeLists.txt
            package.xml
            test.cpp
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(simple_test)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--version ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_VARIABLE ld_version)
if ("${ld_version}" MATCHES "GNU gold")
  message("USING GOLD LINKER!")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--disable-new-dtags")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--disable-new-dtags")
endif()

add_compile_options(-std=c++14 -g -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -Werror=return-type) #with debugging symbols

find_package(drake REQUIRED PATHS /home/user/test_ws/src/drake/build/install)
find_package(catkin)

catkin_package()

add_executable(simple_test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(simple_test drake::drake)
```

Comment: What version of Drake are you trying to install?

Comment: The latest master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the first problem yet.

For the second problem, I think is a bug in Drake's install program (see https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18007).  But in any case, never try to install Drake twice in a row, it is unsound.  You should always `rm` the old install before trying a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've temporarily avoided the first issue by building my test file directly inside drake with bazel. Please let me know if you end up finding a solution to the first problem, or if I can provide any additional details.

Comment: If problem (1) _always_ happened, that would be one thing.  I don't understand why it would be Gurobi-related though.  I'll see if I can dig in.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), I cannot repro.

First, I installed Drake latest master via this:

```
env GUROBI_HOME=/home/jwnimmer/Downloads/gurobi951/linux64 \
  bazel run //:install --config=gurobi -- /home/jwnimmer/tmp/wakka
```

This *should* be identical to running `cmake && make install` to that folder.

Then, I build and link a sample program:

```
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/wakka$ cat main.cc
#include "drake/common/find_resource.h"

int main() {
  drake::FindResourceOrThrow(
      "drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/urdf/"
      "iiwa14_primitive_collision.urdf");
  return 0;
}
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/wakka$ g++ --std=c++17 main.cc -Iinclude -Llib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(pwd)/lib -ldrake -omain 
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/wakka$ ./main; echo $?
0
```

The linking seems fine:

```
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/wakka$ readelf -d main

Dynamic section at offset 0x3cf0 contains 31 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdrake.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/jwnimmer/tmp/wakka/lib]
...

jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/wakka$ ldd main
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe2c491000)
.... nothing is shown as 'missing' ...
```

To help, you'll probably need to share a reproducible sample of how you're building.

Comment: That's strange, it's possible my issue is caused by some cmakelist parameters. I've updated my original post with my current build setup.

Comment: If you're not linking using rpaths, then you need to set a LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  As I understand it, https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/pull/143 is the ROS 2 spelling for that so maybe it helps.